# Extracting a javascript object value by key name using regex

Tags: javascript, python, json, regex, beautifulsoup

I have scraped a webpage using `BeautifulSoup` and `requests` and following piece of code is a portion from the whole HTML page.

```js
$create(Web.Scheduler, {
  "model": '{"apt":[0]}',
  "timeZone": "UTC",
  "_uniqueId": "94b3535a4bdaaf329cab5b7fde996f14",
  "allowEdit": false,
  "people":
    "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"John\", \"age\": \"30\"},{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Jane\", \"age\": \"27\"}]",
  "attributes": {},
  "groupBy": "name",
});
```

There is an object with key `"people"`. How can I extract the value of this key using regex i.e.

```js
[{"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": "30"},{"id": 2, "name": "Jane", "age": "27"}]
```

so that I can parse it as a Python dictionary. I can confirm that string `"people"` (with quotes) is unique on the whole page.

So far, I've seen some solutions to extract strings enclosed in quotes. But in this case, I have to use a pattern that matches `"people":` and maybe `"attributes"` key after it can also be used as a stopping point, I have to extract what's in the middle of these two. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re`/`ast` modules to extract the data. For example:

```
import re
from ast import literal_eval


txt = r'''
$create(Web.Scheduler, {
  "model": '{"apt":[0]}',
  "timeZone": "UTC",
  "_uniqueId": "94b3535a4bdaaf329cab5b7fde996f14",
  "allowEdit": false,
  "people":
    "[{\"id\": 1, \"name\": \"John\", \"age\": \"30\"},{\"id\": 2, \"name\": \"Jane\", \"age\": \"27\"}]",
  "attributes": {},
  "groupBy": "name",
});
'''

data = re.search(r'("people".*?),\s*\n', txt, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = literal_eval('{' + data + '}')

# print the result:
print(data['people'])
```

Prints:

```
[{"id": 1, "name": "John", "age": "30"},{"id": 2, "name": "Jane", "age": "27"}]
```